# Need only parent tag when i parse a html tag using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

If i specify **li** in `find_all()` method i should only get the parent elements and not all **li** elements in the html. ofcourse it makes sense that `find_all()` takes all **li** into consideration but i can use child or parent in the loop to get the child list elements. I'm trying to parse only the parent tags and print them in a single block. nested **li** should not be taken into consideration, Please help!

```
<html>
<p>
something
</p>
<li>
text i need
</li>
<li>
text i need
    <ol>
    <li>
    text i need but appended to parent li tag
    </li>
    <li>
    text i need but appended to parent li tag
    </li>
    </ol>
</li>
<li>
text i need
</li>
```

**when i use**

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'html.parser')
for list in soup.find_all("li"):
    output_text = list.get_text()
    print(output_text)
    print("--sep--")
```

**My result should be**

text i need
--sep--
text i need text i need but appended to parent li tag text i need but appended to parent li tag
--sep--
text i need
--sep--

**But my result is**

text i need
--sep--
text i need
--sep--
text i need but appended to parent li tag
--sep--
text i need but appended to parent li tag
--sep--
text i need
--sep--

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `.find_parent` to filter-out unwanted `<li>`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """\
<html>
<p>
something
</p>
<li>
text i need
</li>
<li>
text i need 
    <ol>
    <li>
    text i need but appended to parent li tag
    </li>
    <li>
    text i need but appended to parent li tag
    </li>
    </ol>
</li>
<li>
text i need
</li>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

for li in soup.select("li"):
    if li.find_parent("li"):
        continue
    print(" ".join(li.text.split()))
    print("--sep--")
```

Prints:

```
text i need
--sep--
text i need text i need but appended to parent li tag text i need but appended to parent li tag
--sep--
text i need
--sep--
```